# How to add `try/except` for .write.mode("overwrite")

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pyspark, try-catch

I have a function to write some data to S3 bucket:

```
def write_to_s3(data, s3_path):
    
    data.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s3_path)

    data.write.mode("overwrite").json(s3_path, compression="gzip")
```

How can I add `try / except` statements to catch potential error/exceptions? I couldn't find example online, can someone help please? Thanks.

Something like:

```
def write_to_s3(data, s3_path):
    try:
      data.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s3_path)
    except ????Error as error:
      logging.error(error)
      raise

    try:
      data.write.mode("overwrite").json(s3_path, compression="gzip")
    except ????Error as error:
      logging.error(error)
      raise
```

Comment: can't you just use `except Exception as error` as a catchall?

Comment: Hi @mck I'm thinking something more specific like throw a customized message if the s3_path is invalid, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure which exception that would throw, but if you encountered that exception, you can import that exception in your code and put that in the except clause